# Derech Hashem - Looking for a complete set of online Shiurem?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, product-recommendation, ramchal

I am looking for a complete set of audio Shiurem on the Ramchal's Derech HaShem

- The audio quality should be very good
- Should be no longer than 45 - 50 min per Shiur
- The series should cover the **whole** book. (unfortunately many online Shiurem stop in the middle of the book)

Comment: Rabbi Mendel Kessin has been lecturing on Ramcha"l for numerous years, and I think he has placed videos online. If they're not online, I'm quite certain that he has a CD set. I apologize that currently, my browser is blocking most sites, so I can't research this completely, now. See if you can do a search using his name; you may find something. If possible, ping me either way to inform me of any progress. If you don't find anything, I may be able to ask him, personally.

Comment: See if this link: http://torahthinking.com/r-mendel-kessin/ helps. You'll find various videos on Derech Hashem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[R' Dovid Miller](http://www.yutorah.org/Rabbi_Dovid_Miller), who has served as *Mashgiach Ruchani* of [Yeshiva University](http://yu.edu), has two recorded *shiur* series on [*Derech Hashem*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derech_Hashem) up on [YUTorah.org](http://www.yutorah.org/Rabbi_Dovid_Miller), one from 2005, and one from 2012. (Click on "Collections," and then find-in-page for "Derech Hashem" to find these two collections.)

They comprise 82 and 97 *shiurim*, respectively, and a spot-check indicates that the typical *shiur* length is around 10 minutes.

The [last *shiur*](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/793505/Rabbi_Dovid_Miller/Derech_Hashem_-_Shiur_97) in the second series bears the note

> This is the end of the sefer. יישר כח to Rav Miller and all those who have learned with us the whole way through.

so it seems that the series does cover the whole book.

I have not yet listened to these *shiurim*, so I can't yet testify about the quality of either the content or the audio.